# How to add dynamically form fields with field type

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make an add dynamically form fields with form fields type. The example is given below.

[image]

I have tried something below but need input type

```
$(function()
 {
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
}).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
{
    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Please try to be more specific with regard to what is or isn't working in the code shown. Also provide enough html to make that code runnable. Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve] then edit the question with properly detailed problem description and relevant code

Comment: You can use the .html() or .append() commands to insert any element you want into the HTML. It's not really clear what the difficulty is. Just write a HTML string containing the elements you and add them to the DOM. You seem to know how to do that already - you've got code which adds a `<span>`. Now you just need to make it add an `<input>` instead

Answer (score -1):

Why not use pure js instead?
Just add an event listener for change of the check button,
Then use if statement for if the value = on then, change the style value of visibility to visible else then hidden.